# Trying to validate characters in string - Java

Tags: java, string, validation, compare

hoping I can get some help. I'm new here and a student developer.

I'm trying to validate a string to ensure it has only characters included in another string.

There is a string of random generated characters (12 in length) and the user inputs a word but must only use characters from the string.

I also need to repeat the user input until there is a valid input. so a loop is necessary. I have tried numerous approaches but for some reason can't get it right

The user input will be within the main class which then calls a method from another class.

My logic is to check if the characters from the user input do not match the characters in the randomLetters String then count. and while that value is greater than 0 then there is an invalid entry so the use should try again. however, what actually is happening is: no matter what the user inputs the code still continues to show that it is incorrect

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class TestValidChar{


    private String player1Guess;
    private final String ALPHABET;
    private String randomLetters;
    private StringBuffer strBuff;
    private String testValid;
    private int validCounter;

    public TestValidChar(){

        player1Guess=" ";
        player2Guess=" ";
        ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        testValid = " ";
        validCounter=0;
    }

    public void setPlayer1Guess(String player1Guess){
        this.player1Guess=player1Guess.toLowerCase();
    }
    public void setPlayer2Guess(String player2Guess){
        this.player2Guess=player2Guess.toLowerCase();
    }

    public void setRandomLetters(String randomLetters){
        randomLetters=" ";
        strBuff = new StringBuffer();
            //for loop to create a string of 12 random letters -
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            // generate a random number between
            // 0 to 25 (instead of 1-26 for lenght of alphabet)
            int index = (int)(ALPHABET.length()* Math.random());
            // add Character one by one to strBuff
            strBuff.append(ALPHABET.charAt(index));
            }//end for loop
        randomLetters = strBuff.toString();

        this.randomLetters=randomLetters;
    }



    public void compute(){
    validCounter=0;
        for(int i=0; i<player1Guess.length(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<randomLetters.length(); j++){
                if(player1Guess.charAt(i)!=randomLetters.charAt(j)){
                    validCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public String getRandomLetters(){
        return randomLetters;
        }

    public int getValidCounter(){
        return validCounter;
        }
}
```

and the app class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestApp{
    public static void main(String[]args){

    //data members
    String player1Guess;
    String player2Guess;
    final String ALPHABET;
    String randomLetters=" ";
    int validCounter;


    TestValidChar myTest = new TestValidChar();
    myTest.setRandomLetters(randomLetters);
    randomLetters=myTest.getRandomLetters();

    player1Guess=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Enter word using these letters: " +randomLetters);
    myTest.setPlayer1Guess(player1Guess);

    myTest.compute();
    validCounter=myTest.getValidCounter();


    while(validCounter>0){

        player1Guess=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Invalid Characters used. Use only " +randomLetters+ " " +validCounter);
        myTest.compute();

        validCounter=myTest.getValidCounter();

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: First is, your class TestValidChar is not compilable. You didn't declare variable player2Guess. Please post only compilable code. Second it is impossible to end the application by pressing the cancel button. Third please get the indentation right. It's hard to read with the wrong indentation. Every IDE has the functionality to format the code properly. Then start go to your method `compute()`, set a breakpoint and start your program in debug mode. Step through the code and try to understand what the heck is going on. In the end you should come to the conclusion that your code is wrong and why.

Comment: Hint: Try to identify the subproblem to check whether one specific character is contained in a string. Write a separate function for that and use it in your `compute()` method. Try to solve the subproblem first. Try it out. And then try to solve the main problem by using your new function. Divide and conquer.

Comment: Hi McButcher,  I feel the pain.  Thirty years ago, when  I was a senior at university, our club held office hours and students would come in to our office at the end of their wits.
</nostalgia>

You made the classic error of typing up all the functionality without testing anything.  Don't ever do that again.  As @vanje said, divide and conquer.  Fix your loop problem first by looping until the user enters "a" as input.  That way you divide the input problem from the string comparison problem.  Then work on the actual comparison part.   Put lots of System.out.printlns or use your debugger.

Comment: ... to look at what the values of your intermediate variables actually are.

Comment: Hi both, (Vanje and Ssimm) - thanks for the comments. 

Vanje, I have the code compiling and running but I can't figure out why the loop is calculating as it is. like I said I am a student so I am learning. 

Simm, I have done some testing but just not understanding why the outcomes are not what I expect them to be. this code is actually part of a much larger program but I decided to share the code that I need help with rather than the whole program. this is the only area I am having issues with currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue lies in the compute method

```
public void compute(){
    validCounter=0;
        for(int i=0; i<player1Guess.length(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<randomLetters.length(); j++){
                if(player1Guess.charAt(i)!=randomLetters.charAt(j)){
                    validCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

First of all it is ambiguous, there is a variable named validCounter but it seems you increment it when 2 characters do not match. It is very important for everyone involved in your code, especially you, of course, to provide meaningful names.

Try to watch step by step why this counter will not have the value you expect. Take for example "word" as a player1Guess and "drow" as randomLetters and iterate through the loops to see why it will increment a number of times, although you expect it not to and then update your logic accordingly.

If you want "validCounter" to increment only when a letter is not found in the "randomLetters" you could rename it to "invalidCounter" and try the following:

```
public void compute() {
    invalidCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < player1Guess.length(); i++) {
        if (randomLetters.indexOf(player1Guess.charAt(i)) == -1) {
            // indexOf returns -1 if char is not found
            invalidCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cristian, thanks for the comment. I understand what you mean, and actually the code I have shared is indeed just a test app, I have tried to validate both valid input and invalid input but didnt't change the variable, in my actual program I will indeed change the name of the variable to either valid or invalid depending on which route I actually take.

Comment: what I mean is, this code is just for testing purposes and the variable name wasnt changed because I am just trying to figure out how to validate. sorry if it is ambiguous I will try to make it more understandable in future posts. I will try your advice now and hopefully fix it

Comment: I understand. Ok, great! Yes, it's important here as well, as it is harder for others to engage and help if it is ambiguous. Good luck! Don't forget to upvote/mark the answer you find useful as solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fix your code as follows:

```
public boolean compute() {
    validCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < player1Guess.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < randomLetters.length(); j++) {
            if (player1Guess.charAt(i) == randomLetters.charAt(j)) {
                // I found a match. The character at player1Guess[i] is ok
                validCounter++;
                break;              
            }                       
        }                   
    }               
    
    // if all characters are OK returns true.
    return validCounter == player1Guess.length();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing. I have use another method, which worked. I will for sure test this out too